# System does not boot DVD drive in secure boot/UEFI mode

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, secure-boot

I had to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Support to be able to boot a Windows 8.1 64bit DVD from the CD drive in the BIOS menu to install Windows.

Is there any reason why this happens? Is there not a way to keep secure boot enable and boot from the DVD drive? I had no option even when enabled from within the BIOS.

This is a Self burned ISO/DISK if that matters. Never heard of that being an issue before.

Comment: is this a selfmade ISO/burned DVD or an official DVD?

Comment: Self burned ISO/DISK

Comment: Depending how it was burned, it may not have UEFI support . . .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the *Windows USB/DVD download tool*, you have to manually add EFI support. Search for it on Google or give [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) a try.